# Is there a way to validate an empty control picker (that receives an integer value) in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin forms, and I'm trying to validate a control picker. When I submit (if I do not select any option) I got the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Below is a small snippet of what I was trying to do. But it has some issues and any inputs would be helpful!

This is part of my viewModel:

```
public class MainOrderViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Horarios _horarioId { get; set; }

    public MainOrderViewModel()
    {
        _horarioId = new Horarios();
    }

    public List<Horarios> Horario
    {
        get { return _horario; }
        set
        {
            _horario = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Horarios HorarioId
    {
        get { return _horarioId; }
        set
        {
            _horarioId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand SendToMainCommonOrderCommand => new Command(async () =>
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_horarioId.HoId.ToString()))
        {
                // Id value that I need with value Zero for simple validation
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, my view:

```
<Picker 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Horario}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding HoHorario,StringFormat='{0}:00hs'}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding HorarioId}"
    Title="Selecciona un horario de almuerzo"
    TextColor="Gray">
</Picker>
```

Comment: try `_horarioId.HoId?.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `ToString()` method when `_horarioId.HoId` is `null`. That's why you get the exception.

**Solution:**

Check whether `_horarioId.HoId` is `null` before call `ToString()`:

```
public ICommand SendToMainCommonOrderCommand => new Command(async () =>
{
    if (_horarioId.HoId == null)
    {
        //set the values here you want when _horarioId.HoId is null
        //for example
        _horarioId.HoId = "";
        //Or
        _horarioId.HoId = 0;
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_horarioId.HoId.ToString()))
    {
        //Id value that i need with value Zero for simple validation
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to make these corrections, but the problem persists. Since the moment the instruction reaches my line in question (Regardless of whether I declare it null to my id). The error remains the same.

Comment: Can you debug what is the value of _horarioId.HoId when you reach the line _horarioId.HoId.ToString()?